# Winner meter - filled based on whose winning

Tags: java, math, logic

I apologize for the title, couldn't think of a better one.

So I'm writing a game, in the there are two players. Based on whose winning, I need a bar to fill, like this:

██████▒▒▒▒▒

^P1 -> P2

If player 1 is winning, there will be more black in the meter.

if Player 2 is winning, there will be more gray.

The issue I'm having, is coming up with the logic of it. Each player has a score, which ranges from 1 to 100,000. The player with more score will be winning, but it needs to show how much they are winning on the meter.

I'm asking if you can come up with the logic for:

- The player who is winning, fill the meter appropriately

I have the meter working, just not sure how to get it to be winning based on a player's score.

Answer (score 5):

I would add both scores together and then each player would have a % of this total. Then make the bar that % that color. Watch for rounding errors.

Comment: Something like this? [link]http://pastebin.com/6n9epf7N[/link]

Edit: Did I do it right?